# Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: username:password@192.192.xx.xxx: invalid IPv6 address

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I have elastic cluster with secure connection of search guard. I am 
trying to connect elastic search with elastic4s using scala  language.

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticsearchClientUri
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.{ElasticClient, 
 ElasticProperties}

object Elastic_new extends App {

import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.ElasticDsl._

 val client = 
 ElasticClient(ElasticsearchClientUri
 ("https://user:pwd@192.192.xx.xxx:9205"))

}
```

I have tried different urls in 
ElasticClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(urls)) but still not able to 
connect it. Is there some properties in ElasticClient that I need to add?
How can I do that ?